# Apache2 Logs, need help in identifying if it is an attack or not

Tags: apache, wordpress

Are this an example of an attack that had happened to my server?

This happened few days before I checked the logs... I checked the logs to see if something was wrong since my server suddenly uses all of its resources ( CPU and Memory )...

Edit: I have a cron that ran every day that clears access_log which is an idiotic thing to do (removed it today).

[image]

Comment: It's very likely a hacking attempt.  Wordpress is a very common target.

Comment: I am using wordfence as a security plugin, it worked well and blocked some attacks on the server but not this time... atm I was relying on it and some basic firewalls... It's time to search some methods to help strengthen the security of the server.

Thanks for confirming @SteveSether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be an attack as well as the preparation for an attack.
Most likely one tries to find out about installed wordpress plugins or (depending on your apache/nginx config) just tries various default names for files (calles website enumeration) to figure out what you are doing. This might lead to some attempt to actually breach the site or he may just collect data. [This article](https://www.troyhunt.com/enumerationis-enumerating-resources-on-a-website-hacking/) shows what happens if you do this on govt sites ;). If it is an actual attempt the attacker probably collected a lot of exploits, set some dependencies (like './cmv.php must exist and return...') and tries to execute them. (You could tell from more detailed access-logs.)

Anyway. If your access logs were more precise you could distinguish those two options but chances are you don't need to. This happens to most of the public IPs that have port 80 or 443 exposed on a daily basis because there is a lot of automated scanning and exploitation going on. If your security basis is working well (such as updates, maybe ModSecurity and so on) it's nothing to really worry about.

Comment: Thanks for the article link ( reading it atm ). My server has not been updated for a few months that have accumulated 140+ updates waiting to be downloaded. I'm also researching regarding website enumeration that you have mentioned.

Comment: Nova Scottia did retract that claim, btw. Please do not link articles that are already outdated. Also, additional plus: The logs look like someone is scanning specifically for already installed SKOTS (Script Kiddie of the shelf) web shells. Maybe you should consider adding this aspect to your answer.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser I see, noted and thanks for the additional plus too :)